# regular expression in Python to update string in a file

Tags: python, regex

Anything that starts with `<a class=“rms-req-link” href=“https://rms.` AND ends with `</a>` should be replaced by TBD.

Example:

```
<a class=“req-link” href=“https://doc.test.com/req_view/ABC-3456">ABC-3456</a>
```

or:

```
<a class=“req-link” href=“https://doc.test.com/req_view/ABC-1234">ABC-1234</a>
```

Such strings should be replaced by TBD in the file.

Code I tried:

```
import re

output = open("regex1.txt","w")
input = open("regex.txt")

for line in input:
    output.write(re.sub(r"^<a class=“req-link” .*=“https://([a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+).*</a>$", 'TBD', line))

input.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly format the code in your question.

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2221001 And while that is more-or-less a joke answer, it likely fits here. It may make more sense to use a module that is purpose built to parse HTML to perform this task.

Comment: Also: Obligatory mention of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: As for the specifics of your question, you say in the first line that the pattern is that it starts with `<a class=“rms-req-link” href=“https://rms.` but in your two examples the `class` for the `a` tag is different and the `href` url is also a different pattern. Can you clarify?

Comment: Remove `^` and `$`, they mark start/end of string.

Comment: You are doing `</a>$` but you're going over lines of a file, so it's probably `</a>\n$`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the pattern you mention does not match the one you use in your code, nor does it correspond to the example strings you want replaced. So you may or may not want to adjust the following pattern depending on what you *actually* need.

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path


PATTERN = re.compile(r'<a\s+class=“req-link”\s+href=“https://.*?</a>')


def replace_a_tags(input_file: str, output_file: str) -> None:
    contents = Path(input_file).read_text()
    with Path(output_file).open("w") as f:
        f.write(re.sub(PATTERN, "TBD", contents))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    replace_a_tags("input.txt", "output.txt")
```

The `.*?` is important to match lazily (as opposed to greedily) so that it matches any character (`.`) between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible until it hits the closing anchor tag.

The pattern matches both your example strings.

The [`Path.read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) method obviously reads the entire file into memory, so that may be a problem, if it happens to be *gigantic*, but I doubt it. The benefit is that the global regex replacement is *much* more efficient than iterating over each line in the file individually.